# Python Flask mobile apps

Tags: python, flask

I was wondering if it's possible to turn a flask app into a mobile app in python3? And what the best frameworks for deploying such app to an app store.

Comment: You can run the server locally then run a electron or some kind of browser to view it on the same device? It's kind of complex though and something like Kivy or pygame would work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flask can only be use to build web applications. You can use Kivy

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned already, you can use Kivy, which is a tool to make cross-platform apps using Python.

Though, there are some options to turn your existing website made on Flask into an **Android** app. Such platforms as appypie (https://appypie.com) provide such an opportunity

Have a good luck :)